# Custom JAXB validation error messages

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb

I am writing a small application which will be used for validating xml-files, correct them (if possible) and then perform tests on the contents. The end users will have very little knowledge of XML and parsing, so I want to catch the validation errors and then write my own event and error handler that produces error messages that are hopefully easier to understand for the end users.

I based my initial attempt on the solution detailed in [this blogpost](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html).

So far I have classified the errors based on the contents of event.getMessage(). Unfortunately, without knowing all types of parsing errors that may occur, it is more or less impossible to write good custom error messages. Is there a good way to find what types of error messages that can occur during validation?

I.e. I am looking for a listing of all messages, e.g. The content of element X is not complete one of ..., Invalid content was found starting with element Y..., Value Z is not facet-valid with respect to pattern...

Or is there some better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of and number of messages will depend on which XML Schema validator you've plugged into JAXB. If you're using one based on Xerces-J (like the one included in Oracle's JDK) most of the messages will be prefixed with an identifier corresponding to a validation rule/constraint in the XML Schema specification (such as `cvc-maxLength-valid`). The list of identifiers for the XML Schema validation rules are available [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#outcomes) in the specification. The full list of XML schema related error messages produced by Xerces can be found in its [XMLSchemaMessages.properties](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xerces/java/trunk/src/org/apache/xerces/impl/msg/XMLSchemaMessages.properties?view=log) message file, but keep in mind that this has changed over time and will depend on which version of Xerces you're using.